# How to find the biggest 'blob' in a binary image

Tags: c#, image-processing, .net-core

I have a 2d array which contains a binary image, all the values are either set to 0 or 255. An example image is as follows:

[image: Binary image]

I'd like to know what the size of each 'blob' is. A blob being the number connected white pixels.

I tried to implement a [distance](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/distance.htm) transform algorithm: 
*(note that the "MatrixData" class is essentially a double[,])*

```
public static MatrixData CalculateDistanceXform(this MatrixData input, int searchDistance)
{
    MatrixData output = new MatrixData(input.NumberOfRows,input.NumberOfColumns);
    for (int r = 0; r < input.NumberOfRows; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < input.NumberOfColumns; c++) 
        {
            //skip black pixels
            if (input[r,c]==0) continue;

            int steps = 0;
            int fxMin = Math.Max(r - searchDistance, 0);
            int fxMax = Math.Min(r + searchDistance, input.NumberOfRows);

            int fyMin = Math.Max(c - searchDistance, 0);
            int fyMax = Math.Min(c + searchDistance, input.NumberOfColumns);

            for (int fx = fxMin; fx < fxMax-1; ++fx)
            {
                for (int fy = fyMin; fy < fyMax-1; ++fy)
                {
                    if(input[fx,fy]==255)
                    {
                        int tempStep = ((fx - fxMin) + (fy - fyMin));
                        if(tempStep > steps) steps = tempStep;
                    }
                }
            }
            output[r,c] = steps; 
        }
    }
    return output.HistEQ();
}
```

However this didn't give me the result i wanted as my blobs are not uniform in size. Any ideas on how to solve this? I essentially want to find a x and y coordinate that is in the largest blob of the image.

Comment: You could modify a flood-fill algorithm which checks each surrounding pixel, keep a mask, check each non masked pixel, keep track of the count. simples.. I leave the rest up to you

Comment: Just FYI, I described a blob detection algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50282882/395685). Might be useful. The actual implementation is available in the `BlobDetection.cs` file in [the source code of the project I used it in](http://nyerguds.arsaneus-design.com/project_stuff/2018/EngieFileConverter/dev/).

Comment: Use connected component labeling. After that you just count the number of pixels in each connected component. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @TheGeneral 's advice a custom flood-fill algorithm worked

Also thanks to [Flood fill recursive algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358513/flood-fill-recursive-algorithm/21358729#21358729)

These methods return a double[,] (MatrixData) with only the largest blob and the center of point of the largest blob.

```
public static MatrixData GetLargestBlob(this MatrixData input, ref Tuple<int, int> blobMid)
{
    MatrixData output = new MatrixData(input.NumberOfRows,input.NumberOfColumns);            
    List<Tuple<int,int>> checkedPixels = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    List<Tuple<int,int>> blobs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    List<Tuple<int,int>> largestBlob = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();            
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int r = 0; r < input.NumberOfRows; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < input.NumberOfColumns; c++) 
        {
            //skip black pixels
            if (input[r,c]==0) continue;

            int replace = rand.Next(256,int.MaxValue);


            if (checkedPixels.Count==0)
            {
                List<Tuple<int,int>> blob = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
                blobs.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(Fill(input,r,c,replace,ref checkedPixels,ref blob), replace)); 
                if(blob.Count > largestBlob.Count) largestBlob = blob;
            } 
            else
            {
                if(!checkedPixels.Contains(new Tuple<int, int>(r, c)))
                {
                    List<Tuple<int,int>> blob = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
                    blobs.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(Fill(input,r,c,replace,ref checkedPixels,ref blob), replace));
                    if(blob.Count > largestBlob.Count) largestBlob = blob;
                }
            }                    
        }
    }

    //set the output to only show the largest blob
    Tuple<int,int> largest = blobs.Where(r => r.Item1 == (blobs.Max(m => m.Item1))).First();
    for (int r = 0; r < input.NumberOfRows; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < input.NumberOfColumns; c++) 
        {
            output[r,c] = (input[r,c]==largest.Item2)? 255 : 0;
        }
    }

    //calculate the center of the largest blob
    int xMin = largestBlob.Min(m => m.Item1);
    int xMax = largestBlob.Max(m => m.Item1);
    int yMin = largestBlob.Min(m => m.Item2);
    int yMax = largestBlob.Max(m => m.Item2);            
    int centerX = ((xMax - xMin) / 2) + xMin;
    int centerY = ((yMax - yMin) / 2) + yMin;
    blobMid = new Tuple<int, int>(centerX, centerY);


    return output;
}

public static int Fill(MatrixData array, int x, int y, int newInt, ref List<Tuple<int,int>> checkedPixels,ref List<Tuple<int,int>> blobPixels)
{
    int initial = array[x,y];
    int counter = 0;
    Queue<Tuple<int,int>> queue = new Queue<Tuple<int,int>>();
    queue.Enqueue(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y));

    while (queue.Any())
    {
        Tuple<int, int> point = queue.Dequeue();

        if (array[point.Item1, point.Item2] != initial)
            continue;

        array[point.Item1, point.Item2] = newInt;
        checkedPixels.Add(point);
        blobPixels.Add(point);
        counter++;
        EnqueueIfMatches(array, queue, point.Item1 - 1, point.Item2, initial);
        EnqueueIfMatches(array, queue, point.Item1 + 1, point.Item2, initial);
        EnqueueIfMatches(array, queue, point.Item1, point.Item2 - 1, initial);
        EnqueueIfMatches(array, queue, point.Item1, point.Item2 + 1, initial);        
    }
    return counter;
}

private static void EnqueueIfMatches(MatrixData array, Queue<Tuple<int, int>> queue, int x, int y, int initial)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= array.Data.GetLength(0) || y < 0 || y >= array.Data.GetLength(1))
        return;

    if (array[x, y] == initial)
    queue.Enqueue(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y));
}
```